# How can I combine line-clamp and text-overflow:ellipsis?

Tags: css

How can I (in Chrome) **combine** "ellipsis if more than 3 lines" and "ellipsis for words that do not fit one line", with pure CSS?

As far as I can see, `-webkit-line-clamp` needs `display:-webkit-box`, but that does prevent `text-overflow: ellipsis` to take effect.

---

In the example, you *should* see **two** ellipses. One ellipsis on the last line, because the whole text is larger, and one ellipsis on the second line, because this word does not fit a line. But that is not the case? How can I achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/5nye9gLj/

```css
p {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    height:56px /* fallback */
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsumnnnnnnnnnn dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.</p>
```

Comment: I don't think you can, even after more than 4 years

Comment: You can always add `word-break: break-all;` or `overflow-wrap: break-word;`  to avoid the problem of `overflow:hidden`

Comment: The caniuse page actually lists this as the behaviour, expected or otherwise: https://caniuse.com/?search=line-clamp "It will end with ellipsis when text-overflow: ellipsis is included."

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want the long word to break to a new line with a hyphen?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the height of the font my hack would be to use a pseudo element to fake the ellipsis. http://jsfiddle.net/syLk4ecx/

```css
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 64px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

p::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 49px;
  left: 0;
  content: '...';
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsumnnnnnnnnnn dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsumnnnnnnnnnn dolor</p>

<p>Lorem dolor</p>
```

This puts the bottom ellipsis in the leading (the spacing between two lines) which is just 1 or 2 pixels high, normally, but you can increase it with `line-height`. This is fragile, the variance of font rendering between devices might be bigger. Also, this depends on the language rendered. For languages (and fonts) with low descenders and high ascenders, this might be even harder to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/syLk4ecx/1/

Comment: I am not the one who downvote, but you are just showing one ellipsis and it should show 2 ellipsis as mentioned in question + this is not customable solution, just fitting with example. REF to question: _"In the example, you should see two ellipses. One ellipsis on the last line, because the whole text is larger, and one ellipsis on the second line, because this word does not fit a line. But that is not the case? How can I achieve this?"_

Comment: This is an ingenious idea. However, it is very fragile. I extended your answer by an explanation what it does and why it is fragile. You get my upvote, you get the bounty, but this is not a reliable solution, in my eyes.

Comment: Thank you @mhchem. I know it's fragile and given people's feedback I think I could have drawn more attention to that fact. If I come up with a better solution as I learn more about CSS I'll be sure to add it